# How can I use the NavigationService as a result of a synchronous callback in Silverlight C# for WP7?

Tags: c#, multithreading, silverlight, windows-phone-7, user-interface

How can I use the NavigationService as a result of a synchronous callback in Silverlight C# for WP7?

Basically, I send an authentication web request on a separate thread, and when it returns success or failure, from a system callback, I need to change the page.

But the Navigation can only occur on the Silverlight UI thread, and I can't find any kind of UI timer functionality to check the status on that thread.

Is it possible, in any way, to initiate a page navigation from a user thread?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Dispatcher.BeginInvoke:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
    NavigationService.Navigate(...);
});
```